# My jquery load script is just not working, why?

Tags: jquery, load

I am simply trying to load a PHP file and replace the content of a div, but I cannot get the load to work.

```
$(document).ready(
    $('img.img1').click(function(){
        $('Close-div-1').load('gcard_save.php');
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "<img src=' http://prisonpulse.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/1363064428581.jpg ' .. />";
    })
);
```

I have ran out of things to try, does anyone know how to solve this?.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping. @wouter I will continue to read the docs, but I just could not figure this out.  And why did my question get voted down? Its a valid question, its very specific and a real problem( for me at least).

Comment: it's down voted because the last 2 things you said: It's very specific (to specific) and it is a real problem for you. It just isn't helpful for others, which means it does not really belong to a Q/A site like SO.  Could you please accept the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every event needs a callback function in jQuery. Please take a look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) and see why this code is completely wrong. Or take a look at the console (Ctrl + J or F12 in IE) and see what error you get.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('img.img1').click(function (){
        $('Close-div-1').load('gcard_save.php');

        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML= "<img src=' http://prisonpulse.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/1363064428581.jpg ' .. />";
    });
});
```

---

EDIT: I had to reformat your code to see this mistake. It really helps you to make your code readable (that means indent consistently, use some whitespace, ect)

Answer (score 0):

There are no `Close-div-1` elements in HTML, I think that you are looking for an id:

```
$('#Close-div-1')
```

or a class:

```
$('.Close-div-1')
```